# Facebook Messenger bot welcome message: 100 The parameter setting_type is required

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, messenger

I'm trying to set a welcome message for a Facebook Messenger bot using the code provided in the documentation - with my own page ID and page access token

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type":"call_to_actions",
  "thread_state":"new_thread",
  "call_to_actions":[{
      "message":{
          "text":"Hello! This is a Messenger bot!"
      }
  }]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<PAGE_ID>/thread_settings?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

This returns the following:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) The parameter setting_type is required","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"B0DKyn9O2KB"}}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: You're using a real PAGE_ID and PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN, right?

Comment: Yes I am. I've checked these are correct multiple times but it's still not working.

Comment: Not working for me either...

Comment: I've had the welcome message working with both the text version and the structured template. Is CURL installed properly?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem! Some strange copy/paste error with the cURL command from fb...

It didn't work with cURL, but then I used "Advanced REST client" (Chrome plugin) and I was able to set the Welcome Message.

[image: FB welcome message in chrome addOn Advanced REST client]

Comment: maybe the specification changed, this is how I had to structure the raw payload: {
  "setting_type":"call_to_actions",
  "thread_state":"new_thread",
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
      "payload":"get_started"
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

I've tried those exact params with my own page and they worked fine.

Can you try these steps?

1. Get your page ID and a fresh access token from the [Facebook developer console](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)
2. Make the request from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer to make sure it isn't a problem with cURL

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and the reason was just stupid:
I made copy paste from FB doc and some quotes were wrong. They were `”` instead of `"`.

Open your file in vi or something and search for all quotes so that u can easily understand which are wrong.

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. 3 quotes were wrong. I wonder why?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i solved it be calling the URL by postman.[check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnF3u.png)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with windows cmd interpreting the commands. Can you try the same code using Cygwin. It worked well for me. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

this is what works for me

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/your_api_id/messages' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer your_App_Token' \
--data-raw '{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "preview_url": false,
    "recipient_type": "individual",
    "to": "33732473829",
    "type": "text",
    "text": {
        "body": "Hello,"
    }
}'
```

I had to specify the access token in the header